# How can I format footer using Python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

How can I format a footer (bold, italic, font-size) using python-docx.
The code below throws an exception (invalid syntax)

```
section = document.sections[0]
footer = section.footer
my_footer = footer.paragraphs[0]
my_footer.text = (f"This ist my {addvariable} footer", style = 'Calibri_10')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can make it bold, for example:

```
section = document.sections[0]
footer = section.footer
my_footer = footer.paragraphs[0]
my_footer.text = f"This ist my {addvariable} footer"
my_footer.runs[0] = bold
```

I'd suggest spending some time with the Quickstart section of the documentation to get a feel for the basic concepts and operations for working with `python-docx`.